# How do I get just enough data in a list in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Say I have a doc in Elasticsearch Index like below

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "color": "RED",
      "qty": 3
    },
    {
      "color": "BLACK",
      "qty": 1
    },    {
      "color": "BLUE",
      "qty": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I just need color BLACK.
Is there any way to get just enough data back like below.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "color": "BLACK",
      "qty": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [script field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-using.html) to generate new field which have only specific value from array. Below is sample query:

```json
{
  "_source": {
    "excludes": "data"
  }, 
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "address": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": """
      List li = new ArrayList();
      if(params['_source']['data'] != null)
      {
        for(p in params['_source']['data'])
        {
          if( p.color == 'BLACK')
            li.add(p);
        }
      }
      return li;
      """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Response:**

```json
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "sample1",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "tUc6338BMCbs63yKTqj_",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : { },
        "fields" : {
          "address" : [
            {
              "color" : "BLACK",
              "qty" : 1
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch returns whole document if there is any match to any field. If you want to find matched nested document, you can make `data` array [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) in your index mapping, write a [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) that filters `data.color` by its value, which is BLACK in your case and use [inner_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/inner-hits.html) to find the matched nested documents.

You can use [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-fields.html#source-filtering) to retrieve only fields you want but it will only filter by fields, not by field values.